# ArcPy RasterUniqueValueColorizer not working correctly

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology

I have a raster layer which consists of unique values 0-4 and I want to color them through ArcPy.

I have tried this:

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
from arcpy.sa import *

#set the pathway to the maps
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(rel_path)

#get the map of interest
one = aprx.listMaps()[0]

#add new layer to map
one.addDataFromPath(new_layer_location)

#get all layers
one_layers = one.listLayers()

#get the first layer
l = one_layers[0]

#build attribute table so I can colorize it
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(l, "Overwrite")

#get symbology
sym = l.symbology

#make a dictionary for changing colors
legend_dict = {'0': {'RGB': [255, 85, 0, 0]}, '1': {'RGB': [0, 92, 230, 0]}, '2':{'RGB': [132, 0, 168, 0]}, '3':{'RGB': [56, 168, 0, 0]}, '4':{'RGB': [255, 255, 255, 0]}}

#set the colors to use based on value
if hasattr(sym, 'colorizer'):
    
    if sym.colorizer.type == 'RasterUniqueValueColorizer': 
       
        sym.colorizer.field = 'Value'
        
        for grp in sym.colorizer.groups:
            
             for itm in grp.items:
                                    
                #change the color
                itm.color = legend_dict[itm.label]
              
               
#update symbology
l.symbology = sym       


#save output
aprx.saveACopy(relpath + r'\\SavedOutput.aprx')
```

but when I look at this output all of the colors in the legend are transparent are have the information of:

```
{'HSV': [0, 0, 100, 0]}
```

I used this information to get this far:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/rasteruniquevaluecolorizer-class.htm

but I am not sure where it is different than what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only thing you need to change is your legend dictionary to:

```py
legend_dict = {'0': {'RGB': [255, 85, 0, 100]}, '1': {'RGB': [0, 92, 230, 100]}, '2':{'RGB': [132, 0, 168, 100]}, '3':{'RGB': [56, 168, 0, 100]}, '4':{'RGB': [255, 255, 255, 100]}}
```

*Note I have changed all the alpha settings from 0 to 100*

Comment: No, I don't think so, that would be fully transparent I believe.  0 should be no transparency.  Verified with my script and the doc I listed.

Comment: Thats not what happened for me. The raster was symbolized. Have you actually tried it? I did run your code within the notebook thats the only difference and the suggested change.

Comment: Yea, I did try it.  Let me try again though with a fresh notebook. Thank you.

Comment: Yea weird, I just needed to save a new copy, thanks again.